# C++ OOP Basic Concept - Passing parameters to constructors

Tags: c++, oop, language-concepts

I don't understand what must be a basic C++ concept related to function parameters. It would really help me if someone could identify what is the concept I'm missing - I'd like to study it in order to deeply understand what's happening.

Consider the simple snippet involving two classes A and B. Creating an object of type A leads to creating an object of type B associated to it. Unfortunately, I'm doing something wrong passing a parameter value creating B.

Output of the following code is:

```
B name: name_value
B name: name_vaHy�
```

Instead of

```
B name: name_value
B name: name_value
```

The name of object B is modified after the constructor call...

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class B{

private:
    string name;
public:
    B(string const& n) : name(n){
        showName();
    }
    void showName(){
        cout << "B name: "  << name << endl;
    }

};

class A{

private:
    B* b;
public :

    A(string const& n)  {
        B b_ = B(n);
        this->b = &b_;
    }

    void show(){
        this->b->showName();
    }
};


int main() {

    string input = "name_value";
    A a = A(input);
    a.show();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `this->b = &b_;` sets the `b` pointer to point to the local variable in the constructor. And that one goes away as soon as the constructor terminates. I would skip the pointer and store a value, like you do with the string in `B`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

object lifetime

If you create a `B` object inside the constructor of `A`, the lifetime of that `B` object is the constructor of `A`. It is destroyed at the end of the constructor. Using a pointer to it after the end of the constructor is undefined behavior.

The `B` object is valid only during the line `A a = A(input);`
When you run the line `a.show();` the `B` object has been destroyed.

You could write the A class like this instead:

```
class A{

private:
    B b;
public :

    A(string const& n) : b(n) {}

    void show(){
        this->b.showName();
    }
};
```

Comment: Scope applies to variable names. Objects have *lifetime*.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation beauxq, very much appreciated.